# Array formula with filter and index values depending on countif

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[image: TABLE SCREENSHOT]

I need an array formula only in column **Date_2** with results like on screenshot and that will

- insert last day of month depending on **Date_0** *(if bunch of Color&Fruit&Meal doesn't repeat in table)*
- insert first minimum date of column **Date_1** *(if bunch of Color&Fruit&Meal repeats first time)* - 1
- insert second minimum date of column **Date_1** *(if bunch of Color&Fruit&Meal repeats second time)* - 1
- and so on...

Is is possible to solve it with array formula?

I've tried but I can't..

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",IF(COUNTIF(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,B2:B&C2:C&D2:D)>1,INDEX(FILTER(B2:E,E2:E<>""),1,4),EOMONTH(A2:A,0))))
```

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RrTfvIyGk6BO_nUeYrM_fQKOw4lF_1XgkRpGDpXLVPY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a duplicate sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in F1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Date_2";IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&TEXT(COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))+1,"000"),{B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&TEXT(COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),"000"),E2:E},2,FALSE)-1,EOMONTH(A2:A,0)))})`

This formula creates the header (which you can change within the formula) and all results for Column F.

To lookup the "next instance of the group if there is one," I just wrote the formula to VLOOKUP that grouping plus a text rendering of the COUNTIFS-as-of-that-row-plus-1 for that grouping within a virtual array of each-grouping-plus-unique-count-thus-far in one column and the E2:E data in the next column. For instance, for Row 2, the formula VLOOKUPs redapplepie002
(002 being the text rendition of 001, which is the count of redapplepie as of row 2).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you need for `Date_1` but try this `arrayformula` in cell `F2` for `Date_2`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date_2";if(IF(B2:B&""&C2:C&""&D2:D<>"",if(A2:A<>"",COUNTIFS(B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:D,B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:D,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),),)=1,eomonth(A2:A,0),)})`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BcBOcxu

Your formula in column G, but I need results like in my manual column F

Comment: In cell `F4`, where do you get your 5/19/2021 from? What is the logic you want?

Comment: its a minimum date for Blue Blueberry Cake from column Date_1 (5/20/2021) - 1

Comment: OK, try `=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date_2";if(IF(B2:B&""&C2:C&""&D2:D<>"",if(A2:A<>"",COUNTIFS(B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:D,B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:D,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),),)=1,vlookup(C2:C&D2:D,{C:C&D:D,E:E},2,false),)})`

Comment: Your sheet has changed. Try `=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date_2";if(IF(B2:B&""&C2:C&""&D2:D<>"",if(A2:A<>"",COUNTIFS(B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:D,B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:D,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),),)=1,vlookup(C2:C&D2:D,{C:C&D:D,F:F},2,false),)})` That's getting the first date in Col F for unique permutations of cols BCD, and looking up CD.

Comment: On your sheet, you only have one cell with value '5/19/2021' (col F). So when it comes to calculating the value for cell G4, if we ignore col F, what's the logic to get 5/19/2021 in col G. Should it be cell E6 minus 1?